# PowerShell Set-ItemProperty LastWriteTime incorrect locale

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am running a powershell script:

sp -Path "c:\myfile.txt" -Name LastWriteTime 01/12/2020

It works, but it interprets the date "01/12/2020" as 12th of January 2020, eg MM/DD/YYYY, even though my locale is DD/MM/YYYY

How can I tell it to use the current (command window) locale instead?